# The list of employees is not displayed

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

The employee is not displayed in the employee list after the screen transition.
I will place JSP, Servlet, and DAO below, and would appreciate your guidance.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.List,model.EmployeeBean"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Employee Management System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<EmployeeBean> employeeList = (List<EmployeeBean>) request.getAttribute("employeeList");
    %>

    <div class="header">
        <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LogoutSevlet"
            method="post">
            <button class="logout" type="submit" value="logout">LOGOUT</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="addButton">
        <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/EmployeeAddServlet"
            method="post">
            <button class="add" type="submit" value="add">New
                Registration</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr class="">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>EMail</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <%
            if (employeeList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {
        %>

        <tr>

            <td><%=employeeList.get(i).getId()%></td>
            <td><%=employeeList.get(i).getName()%></td>
            <td><%=employeeList.get(i).getMail()%></td>


            <td>
                <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/EmployeeDetailServlet"
                    method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=employeeList.get(i).getId()%>">
                     <input type="submit" value="Detailed View">
                </form>
            </td>


        </tr>
        <%
            }
            }
        %>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import dao.EmployeeListDAO;
import model.EmployeeBean;

/**
 * 
 */
/**
 * Servlet implementation class EmployeeListServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/EmployeeListServlet")
public class EmployeeListServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    //  public EmployeeListServlet() {
    //      super();
    //      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //  }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            List<EmployeeBean> employeeList = null;
            EmployeeListDAO dao = new EmployeeListDAO();
            employeeList = dao.selectAll();
            request.setAttribute("employeeList", employeeList);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/employee_list.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //      List<EmployeeBean> employeeList = null;
        //
        //      EmployeeListDAO dao = new EmployeeListDAO();
        //
        //      try {
        //          employeeList = dao.selectAll();
        //      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //          e.printStackTrace();
        //      } catch (SQLException e) {
        //          e.printStackTrace();
        //      }
        //
        //      
        //      request.setAttribute("employeeList", employeeList);
        //
        //      
        //      RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("employee_list.jsp");
        //      rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.EmployeeBean;

/**
 *
 * 
 *
 */

public class EmployeeListDAO {

    public List<EmployeeBean> selectAll() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        List<EmployeeBean> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();

        // DBへの接続の取得など
        try (Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                Statement ptmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet res = ptmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee_table")) {

            //結果の操作
            while (res.next()) {
                String id = res.getString("id");
                String username = res.getString("username");
                String name = res.getString("name");
                String callname = res.getString("callname");
                String birth = res.getString("birth");
                int age = res.getInt("age");
                String gender = res.getString("gender");
                String country = res.getString("country");
                int postal = res.getInt("postal");
                String address = res.getString("address");
                String entry = res.getString("entry");
                String retirement = res.getString("retirement");
                String reason = res.getString("reason");
                String phone = res.getString("phone");
                String mail = res.getString("mail");
                int mynumber = res.getInt("mynumber");
                String password = res.getString("password");
                String text = res.getString("text");

                EmployeeBean employee = new EmployeeBean();
                employee.setId(id);
                employee.setUserName(username);
                employee.setName(name);
                employee.setCallname(callname);
                employee.setBirth(birth);
                employee.setAge(age);
                employee.setGender(gender);
                employee.setCountry(country);
                employee.setPostal(postal);
                employee.setAddress(address);
                employee.setEntry(entry);
                employee.setRetirement(retirement);
                employee.setReason(reason);
                employee.setPhone(phone);
                employee.setMail(mail);
                employee.setMynumber(mynumber);
                employee.setPassword(password);
                employee.setText(text);

                employeeList.add(employee);
            }
        }
        return employeeList;
    }

}
```

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * 
 *
 */

public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private String callname;
    private String birth;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    private int postal;
    private String country;
    private String address;
    private String entry;
    private String retirement;
    private String reason;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;
    private int mynumber;
    private String password;
    private String text;

    /**
     *  EmployeeBean
     */
    public EmployeeBean() {

    }

    public EmployeeBean(String id, String userName, String name, String callname, String birth, int age, String gender,
            String country, int postal, String address, String entry, String retirement,
            String reason, String phone, String mail, int mynumber, String password, String text) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setUserName(userName);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setCallname(callname);
        this.setBirth(birth);
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setGender(gender);
        this.setCountry(country);
        this.setPostal(postal);
        this.setAddress(address);
        this.setEntry(entry);
        this.setRetirement(retirement);
        this.setReason(reason);
        this.setPhone(phone);
        this.setMail(mail);
        this.setMynumber(mynumber);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.setText(text);

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirth() {
        return birth;
    }

    public void setBirth(String birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }

    public void setPostal(int postal) {
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(String entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public int getMynumber() {
        return mynumber;
    }

    public void setMynumber(int mynumber) {
        this.mynumber = mynumber;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getRetirement() {
        return retirement;
    }

    public void setRetirement(String retirement) {
        this.retirement = retirement;
    }

    public String getCallname() {
        return callname;
    }

    public void setCallname(String callname) {
        this.callname = callname;
    }
}
```

I can log in normally, but am I not able to retrieve employee information from the DB? I don't know, because the error is not displayed.

I would appreciate your answer.

Comment: With the given information I cannot really tell what your problem is exactly. Try to do some more debugging: With what database connects your code? Do you have any entries in your "employee_table"? Try and isolate the problem to find the bug you are after.

Comment: A quick way to find the root cause of the problem is to remove the `try-catch` i.e. `} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {` and declare these exceptions with `throws` in the signature of `doGet`.